# Please Help me determine what model/year my BMX bike is

Tags: bmx

I was given a Dyno VFR BMX bike

The Main sticker decal reads " DYNO by GT
Above that another sticker reads " VFR"

The serial underneath the frame Is
" IBDFSD14C2297" any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google "dyno serial number lookup"

Answer (score 2):

Via https://knowyourbike.com/dyno/vfr

> The Dyno VFR is a juvenile/cruiser/bmx bike with a steel and chromoly frame. The frame comes in colors like red, red and green. Originally released in 1996, there are 10 versions of this bike…

And

[image]

From the last two digits of the serial probably a 1997 model